# How to run rspec test in different environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rspec, development-environment

I run my rspec tests in the test environment. But I have one test which has to use the development database. (I run a curl command with RestClient which creates an object in the database (table Photo)) I need to check is that object in the regular database.

In my spec_helper, I have ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'

I tried adding **ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = 'development'** in this single test, but it still says Uninitialized constant Photo.

Any idea?

Comment: That's probably a bad idea that you can't share/user the same code between different environments. I suggest you to have test environment work with your current code as it runs specs as if you'll run your code in production or staging environment.

Answer (score 1):

Try prepending RAILS_ENV=development in the console before your test command.

Uninitialized constants mean that something else isn't set up. Maybe a model or controller is trying to access 'photo'?